# RMI : NotBoundException

Tags: java, rmi

I've implemented an RMI interface with these current files;

```
MyClient.java - Clientside code  
MyServer.java - Serverside code  
Adder.java - Interface  
AdderRemote.java - Remote _implements Adder_  
DataAccess.java - Contains all the methods to interveen between server and client
```

I have a vps which contains all files except the Client file in the directory

```
vps:~/rmi#
```

When testing this on it's own, *ie:* compiling on the server, doing

```
rmic AdderRemote  
rmiregistry 5000&
```

*(the port I have chosen)*

```
java -classpath .:mysql-connector... MyServer
```

and then locally doing the same process but running the MyClient java instead, it works. The problem I am facing is now implementing this into a project I have running in eclipse as a part of this;

I have an instance of MyClient in the main file which is then passed as parameters to the certain classes *(This project implements the MVC pattern and is passed to fellow model class')*, and I am now getting the error

```
java.rmi.NotBoundException: xox
```

after googling, the only response I could find was "Attempt to look up a name that is not bound.", But I'm not really sure what this means? I'll attach my code, and any help would be much appreciated.

MyClient.java

```
public class MyClient 
{
public Adder stub;

public MyClient ()
{
    try 
    {
        stub = (Adder)Naming.lookup("rmi://92.222.2.96:5000/xox");

    } 
    catch (Exception e) 
    {
        System.out.println(e.toString());
    }
}

public static void connect(Adder stub) throws RemoteException 
{
    System.out.println(stub.connect());
}
```

Adder.java

```
public interface Adder extends Remote 
{
public String connect() throws RemoteException;
}
```

AdderRemote.java

```
public class AdderRemote extends UnicastRemoteObject implements Adder 
{
public AdderRemote() throws RemoteException 
{
    super();
    da = new DataAccess();
}

DataAccess da;

public String connect() throws RemoteException
{
    return da.connect();
}
```

DataAccess.java

```
public class DataAccess 
{
// Connection info
static final String URL = "jdbc:mysql://92.222.2.96:3306/groupproj";
static final String DRIVER = "com.mysql.jdbc.Driver";
static final String USERNAME = "root";
static final String PASSWORD = "*****";
Connection c = null;  

public String connect()
{
    try
    {
        Class.forName(DRIVER).newInstance();                                                            //Load DB driver
        c = DriverManager.getConnection(URL, USERNAME, PASSWORD);                                       //Establish connection to DB2
        return "Connected.";                
    }
    catch(Exception e)
    {
        return e.toString();
    }
}
```

MyServer.java

```
 public class MyServer 
 {
    public static void main ( String args[] ) 
    {
            try
        {
                    Adder stub = new AdderRemote();
                    Naming.rebind("rmi://92.222.2.96:5000/xox", stub);
            } 
            catch ( Exception e ) 
            {
                System.out.println(e);
            }
    }

    public static void connect(Adder stub) throws RemoteException
    {
            try
            {
                    stub.connect();
            }
            catch(Exception e)
            {
                    System.out.println("Could not connect to the DB.");
            }
    }
```

I gathered that because the files on the server are located in the directory "rmi" I renamed the xox to this, but this did not solve the problem, so I reverted it back to xox, which it worked *before* putting it into a java project.

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

You must have got an exception doing the bind.

If you got a `NotBoundException` when looking up the same name in the same Registry you're supposed to have bound it to, you didn't bind it at all.

Notes:

- You can only bind to a Registry that is running in the same host as yourself. For that reason it is convenient to always use `"localhost"` as the hostname when calling `bind(), rebind(),` or `unbind().`
- You'd be better off letting the `RemoteException` and `NotBoundException` be thrown from the constructor of `MyClient.`
- `MyClient.connect()` should not be static. In fact it cannot be static. *Ergo* this cannot be the real code.
- From what we can see so far, your system isn't correctly designed. Your server should get a DBMS connection when it needs one, inside a remote method, on behalf of the client that is calling that method, and release it before exiting the method. Opening a new connection every time a client asks for one explicity and storing it into an instance variable of the remote object (a) will leak connections and (b) won't work when concurrent clients come to execute a query or update on the same connection.